# Hahn-Banach implies that zero map extends to zero map?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras, hahn-banach-theorem, representation-of-algebras

Let $H$ be a complex inner product space and $\hat H$ its Hilbert space completion. Consider the bounded linear functional $\phi : H → \mathbb{C}, h ↦ 0$. Does Hahn-Banach tell us that its extension $\hat \phi$ to $\hat H$ must also be the zero map?

EDIT: for some more context, I'm studying the GNS representation $(H_\tau, \phi_\tau)$ of some $C^*$-algebra $A$, where $H_\tau$ is the Hilbert space completion of $A/N_\tau$ for $N_\tau := \{a ∈ A \mid \tau(a^*a) = 0\}$, and for each $a ∈ A$, $\phi_\tau(a)$ is the unique extension of the operator $\phi(a) = (b + N_\tau ↦ ab + N_\tau)$ to $H_\tau$. In my case, I have that $\phi(a)$ is the zero map, and I want to conclude $\phi_\tau(a)$ is as well.

Comment: $\hat{\psi}:=0$ would be *an* extension. Which of the following are you asking: “is the zero map the only extension?” Or “Does the Hahn-Banach proof method construct the zero map as the canonical extension?”

Comment: I'm not sure what 'the' canonical extension is, but I would guess the latter. I've provided some context. Perhaps it has nothing to do with HB at all.

Comment: A continuous extension must be 0 everywhere as it is 0 on a dense subset.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet could you explain why? Is this by continuity alone? Does HB enter the picture at all?

Comment: EDIT: my god, it's just basic topology... This is much less involved that I thought, nvm!

Comment: I've had worse brain cramps on this site.